# The movement of view with applied transformation on iPad Air (with retina display)

Tags: ios, uiview, cgaffinetransform, ipad

If I apply transformation for a view, then movement of the view on iPad Air happens with lags. It looks like implicit animations in CALayer.
I've created test [project](https://github.com/K-Be/ViewMovingTest). It should be executed on iPad simulator.
This is code that I use for apply transformations:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
if (_transformSwitch.on)
{
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0), M_PI / 3.0);
}

self.frameView.transform = transform;
```

This is  code that I use for apply movement:

```
CGPoint transition = [_panRecognizer translationInView:self.view];
CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(_startCenter.x + transition.x, _startCenter.y + transition.y);
self.frameView.center = newCenter;
```

How I can move the view with applied transformations and avoid the animations?

**UPD** 
I've found a solution for a moving by timer invocation, but if I'm moving frame by a finger, I've have problem with the animation.
I set a center of the view  with wrapping it with [CATransaction begin] [CATransaction commit]:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:@(YES) forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];

_destinationIndicatorView.center = center;
self.frameView.center = center;

[CATransaction commit];
```

I've found strange solution, but I want to know why is it a worked solution?
I added to this method setNeedsDisplay, and it's solved my problem. (If I add any view over my screen with drawRect method, and call setNeedsDisplay on it view, it's also solved my problem):

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:@(YES) forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];

_destinationIndicatorView.center = center;
[self.frameView setNeedsDisplay];

self.frameView.center = center;

[CATransaction commit];
```

I've updated my project.

**UPD2** 
This lag happens only on iPad with retina display (for example iPad Air). I've created small video to illustrate the problem: https://yadi.sk/i/rAneCEFmjjEej

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: can you to off switch near slider and move a frame with flier by finger. If you move your finger quick, then the frame will be behind  your finger.

Comment: Problem with location of a center of the frame while your move your finger fast. For more effect, you can change line transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.3, 2.3), M_PI / 3.0); to transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(10.0, 10.0), M_PI / 3.0);

Comment: I've updated the project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could wrap the changes in this code:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction disableActions];

// Your changes to the UI elements...

[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Did you open my project?

Comment: Yes, and I've found solution but do not understand why it works

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've played around with your project and found 2 things that do not what you expected they would do:

The 1st one is `drawRect:` on `FrameView`:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
}
```

From Apple:

> The default implementation of this method does nothing. Subclasses
>   that use technologies such as Core Graphics and UIKit to draw their
>   view’s content should override this method and implement their drawing
>   code there. You do not need to override this method if your view sets
>   its content in other ways. For example, you do not need to override
>   this method if your view just displays a background color or if your
>   view sets its content directly using the underlying layer object.

The 2nd one is the wrong (it's right according to the doc, see below) return value of the overridden `- (id<CAAction>)actionForLayer:(CALayer *)layer forKey:(NSString *)event` on FrameView: you return `nil` (as described in the `CALayerDelegate` reference) while CoreAnimation, in fact, expects an instance of `NSNull` (as might be assumed when reading `CALayer` class reference). Your actions led to an unintended result as there's a collision in the documentation. I'm talking about [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/actionForKey:) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CALayerDelegate_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/actionForLayer:forKey:).

P.S. As a result, I made it working without using `CATransaction`. Unfortunately, I don't have a retina iPad by hand, so please check out my changes to your GitHub project (I will create a pull request containing all my changes) and tell if it resolves both the unintended animation (assuming resolved) problem and the lag of dragging (need to check for performance issues on a real iPad).

Comment: It is good, what we can remove empty drawRect method from FrameView. But nothing changed, we should call setNeedsDisplay, to avoid implicit animation. About  NSNull you are right (this erratum, which I did not see), but it is equivalent to CATransaction block: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/ReactingtoLayerChanges/ReactingtoLayerChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH7-SW6.

Comment: I think, without drawRect method invocation setNeedsDisplay on view do nothing. But layer has not clear draw rect, therefore setNeedsDisplay works any timers.

Comment: Without understanding of the animations mechanism we can't create correct good solution. May be it is bug?

Comment: @AndrewRomanov, I've amended my changes with some new performance tweak attempts. Please check those out.

Comment: Video: https://yadi.sk/i/Dk-PHpjDjkGpv 
I think, using of the rasterisation is a good idea, I've tried it before, and it did not solve problem (before I use scale == 2.0). 
If scale more, then the problem more visible.

Comment: Let's talk here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92260/room-for-arthur-gevorkyan-and-andrew-romanov